# Power BI - Network graph using NetworkX in Python

Tags: python-3.x, powerbi, networkx

I've been exploring NetworkX in PowerBI.

If I load the tables;

Nodes table

| NodeName | Pathway |
| --- | --- |
| A | A |
| B | A\B |
| C | A\B\C |
| D | A\B\D |

Edges table

| From | To |
| --- | --- |
| A\B\C | A\B\D |
| A\B\D | A\B |
| A\B | A |

Then duplicate the Nodes table and form the Relationships;

```
NodesFrom[Pathway] <-----> Edges[From] 1:Many
NodesTo[Pathway] <-----> Edges[To] 1:Many
```

Dropping the two NodeName(s) into a table I see

| NodeNameFrom | NodeNameTo |
| --- | --- |
| C | D |
| D | B |
| B | A |
| A |  |

Where A is mapped to a blank ""

I've put this into a Python visual using NetworkX and NetworkX is displaying this Blank Node as well. I've tried to remove it using the following as it shows as "NaN"

```py
#remove_nodes = []
#for node in G.nodes():
#    if math.isnan(node):
#        remove_nodes.append(node)
#G.remove_nodes_from(remove_nodes)
```

```py
# The following code to create a dataframe and remove duplicated rows is always executed and acts as a preamble for your script: 

# dataset = pandas.DataFrame(NodeName, NodeName.1)
# dataset = dataset.drop_duplicates()

# Paste or type your script code here:

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(dataset, source="NodeName", target="NodeName.1")

#remove_nodes = []
#for node in G.nodes():
#    if math.isnan(node):
#        remove_nodes.append(node)
#G.remove_nodes_from(remove_nodes)

nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels = True)
plt.show()
```

1. How would I remove these Blank Nodes that weren't in my original Nodes table?
2. The relationships are directed, but the graph is drawing them as undirected. How do I force the graph to draw them as Directed? I have tried to add `arrowstyle="->"` in
   `G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(dataset, source="NodeName", target="NodeName.1", arrowstyle="->")` but this doesn't draw the graph.

If I add another table in containing attributes of the Nodes and put in either of the relationships;

```
NodesFrom[NodeName] <-----> Attributes[NodeName] 1:Many 
NodesTo[NodeName] <-----> Attributes[NodeName] 1:Many
```

Attributes table

| NodeName | Property | Property Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | Property 1 | Filter Value |

I can now filter the Nodes and depending on the relationship as either From or To.
This makes the graph draw only A -> B or B -> C

3. How do I make the graph draw the full upwards or downwards paths so if there were more unconnected Nodes e.g. "E" and "F" they would not be drawn as they are not of interest but for example B -> C -> D will still be drawn?

Comment: can you provide the reproducible constructors of your inputs (as code)?

Comment: Sorry - I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: @Dan To translate: right now, if we want to run your code, we have to try to copy your table by hand. It would be helpful if you would give us something that we could copy and paste directly

Comment: Ah - Thanks @BenGrossmann. I can't provide the PBIX file, but I've put the sample data into csvs, just can't see how to upload that.

Comment: How can you run Networkx in PowerBI? I thought it was not supported